# Materialize nav bar issue

Tags: html, css, materialize

So I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pluqk.png) navbar made with materialize

My code is:

```
<nav class="light-blue lighten-1 " role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container "><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Treasure Hunt</a>

        <ul id="navbarUl" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Misiuni</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NewsFeed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clasament</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">  </a></li>
            <li id="navbarLi"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s6"><a id="navbarImg" href="#"><img src="img/asd.jpg" class="circle responsive-img small"/></a></div>
                    <div class="col s6">Adyzds</div>






                </div>
            </li>

            <li >
                <div class="row">


                    <div class="col s4"><a href="#">Level:</a>
                        <span>Value</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4"><a href="#">XP:</a>
                        <span>Value</span>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My mouse is over the profile pic. I would like the hover effect to cover the name too. Also, I would like the Level value to be near Level.
Can anyone help me?

CSS:

```
 .icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.icon-block .material-icons {
    font-size: inherit;
}
#navbarImg{
    padding-top: 10px;
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 64px;
}
#navbarLi{
    max-height: 64px;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the image, "Value" is underneath the level. I want it to be near level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your columns are too narrow for Level: + value. Instead of creating a row with 2 columns inside, try using seperate `<li>` for each:

```
<li >
   <a href="#">Level: <span>7</span> </a>
</li>    
<li>
   <a href="#">XP:<span>105</span> </a>
</li>
```

As for your name, just nest it in a `<a>` element and materialize will know what to do with it.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwxa6e80/3/ ... hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah, this helped. Also, could you please show me how to  place the Photo and the Name(Adyzds) under the same li, and not get one underneath other? Under the same HREF I mean

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, can do so by giving both the <img> and <span> a display: inline-block; and vertical-align: middle.